# Deleting empty folders inside a folder for iTunes Media cleanup (Mac)

Tags: mac, itunes, music, disk-cleanup, files-folders

My iTunes library has some time ago split up into two locations and now I want to merge them, but before I do so I want to clean up the folders. In the iTunes Media list, there are artist folders, leading to album folders and these may contain songs. However, many of these are empty, so I am trying to find a way how to delete all the subfolders (album folders) that are empty within the complete artist folder list and in the case that there are only empty album folders for an artist, to delete the artist folder as well. Hope one of you can help me out here!

Answer (score 0):

How are you actually planning to 'merge' them?
The two cleanest methods would be by Importing one half on top of the other in an existing Library, or by discarding the existing Library then drop the whole lot onto a newly created Library as an import… either by ensuring 'keep organised' is *on* before import or by later Consolidating to the new default location.

This second, new Library, method will at the same time get rid of all the unused file/folder structure [by the simple expedient of not re-creating it in the new location.]

Comment: The first method was the one I had in mind, but the second one I don't fully understand. You suggest creating a new, third, folder and drag and dropping everything in there? How will that remove the folders that contain no songs?

Comment: 'Keep organised' or the post-process Consolidate work by copying all your tunes to a new structure, making the folder hierarchy as it goes. Never try to out-guess it by making your own folder hierarchy. You Import to iTunes, it makes the structure. Once the Import is finished you can delete the original structure the Import was done from. Without either of these settings, your files stay wherever they were, meaning if you ever move or delete any, iTunes gets confused.

Comment: This would be working if there was enough space to create copies from the old folder and only delete the original afterwards, but there unfortunately is not. So that brings me back to the question how to get rid of the empty folders inside the artist folders. If you have any other ideas please let me know!

Comment: Asking for someone to write you a script or recommend software is off-topic, but to throw you a bone - https://www.tempel.org/FindEmptyFolders [untested]